# Get current header of the tabView PrimeNG

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, tabview

I'd like to get current header of the PrimeNG tabView. I tried to do it by binding activeIndex property but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a reference to your tabView in your component using @ViewChild and bind to a variable the selectedIndex then you can get the header of selected tavview `this.tabView.tabs[this.selectedIndex].header`.

Below a sample code:
app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
//imports
import {TabView, TabPanel} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedIndex = 0;
  //class variable
  @ViewChild(TabView) tabView: TabView;

  onChange($event) {
    this.selectedIndex = $event.index;
  }

  getSelectedHeader(){
    console.log(this.tabView.tabs[this.selectedIndex].header);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h2>PrimeNG Issue Template</h2>
<button pButton (click)="getSelectedHeader()" label="selected header"></button>
<p-tabView (onChange)="onChange($event)" [activeIndex]="selectedIndex">
  <p-tabPanel header="first" [selected]="true">
    <first></first>

  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="second" cache="false">
    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
      <second></second>
    </ng-template>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

[A working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ARI3ZX9tJxdOUBGq3Cjr?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Thanks, this helped me too

Comment: Plunker code doesn't render tab component and gets stuck on Loading...

Comment: For those who facing issues with the `TabView` import, please change `import {TabView, TabPanel} from 'primeng/primeng';` to `import {TabView, TabPanel} from 'primeng/tabview';`

Answer (score 3):

> .html

```
<p-tabView #tabView (onChange)="tabViewChange($event, tabView)">...</p-tabView>
```

> .ts

```
tabViewChange(event, tabView: TabView) {
 const headerValue = tabView.tabs[event.index].header;
}
```